# setting innerHTML in xul

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I have  in my browser.xul code,what I am tyring to is to fetch data from an html file and to insert it into my div element.
I am trying to use div.innerHTML but I am getting an exception:

> Component returned failure code: 0x804e03f7
>   [nsIDOMNSHTMLElement.innerHTML]

I tried to parse the HTML using Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableUnescapeHTML and to append the parsed html into my div but my problem is that style(attribute and tag) and script isn`t parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a warning: if your HTML data comes from the web then you are trying to build a security hole into your extension. HTML code from the web should never be trusted (even when coming from your own web server and via HTTPS) and you should really use `nsIScriptableUnescapeHTML`. Styles should be part of your extension, using styles from the web isn't safe. For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Displaying_web_content_in_an_extension_without_security_issues

As to your problem, this error code is NS_ERROR_HTMLPARSER_STOPPARSING which seems to mean a parsing error. I guess that you are trying to feed it regular HTML code rather than XHTML (which would be XML-compliant). Either way, a better way to parse XHTML code would be [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Parsing_and_serializing_XML#Parsing_strings_into_DOM_trees), this gives you a document that you can then insert into the right place.

If the point is really to parse HTML code (not XHTML) then you have two options. One is using an `<iframe>` element and displaying your data there. You can generate a `data:` URL from your HTML data:

```
 frame.src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(htmlData);
```

If you don't want to display the data in a frame you will still need a frame (can be hidden) that has an HTML document loaded (can be `about:blank`). You then use [`Range.createContextualFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.createContextualFragment) to parse your HTML string:

```
var range = frame.contentDocument.createRange();
range.selectNode(frame.contentDocument.documentElement);
var fragment = range.createContextualFragment(htmlData);
```

Comment: My main problem is using iframe,because it has some problems with iframe in panel.About the second option using iframe to parse the data,where do you suggest to set the parsed data?in html:div it can be unsafe.

Comment: If security is an issue (the data doesn't come from your extension or the user but rather from some web server) then you shouldn't use this kind of HTML parsing in the first place. It is really either `<iframe type="content">` or `nsIScriptableUnescapeHTML`.

Comment: The data comes from my extension (html file).using iframe is problematic(panel and iframe as a child issues) and nsIScriptableUnescapeHTML is problematic too because it removes style and script.

Comment: Then you simply do `div.appendChild(fragment)` - if the data is part of your extension then it is safe.

Comment: But then I have another problem - If the user will set div { background-color:red; } it will change my html:div style.

Answer (score 0):

XML documents don't have `innerHTML`, and `nsIScriptableUnescapeHTML` is one way to get the html parsed but it's designed for uses where the HTML might not be safe; as you've found out it throws away the script nodes (and a few other things).

There are a couple of alternatives, however. You can use the `responseXML` property, although this may be suboptimal unless you're receiving XHTML content.

You could also use an iframe. It may seem old-fashioned, but an iframe's job is to take a url (the `src` property) and render the content it receives, which necessarily means parsing it and building a DOM. In general, when an extension running as chrome does this, it will have to take care not to give the remote content the same chrome privilages. Luckily that's easily managed; just put `type="content"` on the iframe. However, since you're looking to import the DOM into your XUL document wholesale, you must have already ensured that this remote content will always be safe. You're evidently using an HTTPS connection, and you've taken extra care to verify the identity of the server by making sure it sends the right certificate. You've also verified that the server hasn't been hacked and isn't delivering malicious content.

Comment: XML documents do have `innerHTML` but it is designed to take XML-compliant data.